# Cannot export org mode to collapsible HTML

Tags: org-mode, html

I am trying to have basic collapsing/folding functionality for sections in the HTML file that has been exported from org-mode, since the files I want to share are very large. I am using Emacs 26.2 (9.0) and Org 9.1.9 on a Mac. I am not able to get [this previous solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/how-do-i-export-an-org-file-to-an-interactive-html-site) to work in 2019.

This seems like a built in [feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/JavaScript-support.html) but it seems like the underlying javascript code has a bug. I also saw another [tool](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-03/msg00472.html) mentioned on the mailing lists, but without any examples I don't know how apply it to a specific org file I have.

For example, the following file is converted to HTML [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/docs/minimal_org)

```
#+Title+: JS test
#+INFOJS_OPT: path:/~ksb/js/org-info.js
#+INFOJS_OPT: toc:nil ltoc:nil view:overview mouse:underline
#+INFOJS_OPT: home:https://orgmode.org buttons:nil
* Chapter 1
** Section 1
*** Part 1
 - csp
** Section 2
 - cs2p
```

I have a freshly-downloaded copy of [js/org-info.js](http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/js/org-info.js).

UPDATE: there is a javascript error being raised by org-info.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined
    at Object.initFromTOC (org-info.js:82)
    at Object.init (org-info.js:49)
    at OrgHtmlManagerLoadCheck (org-info.js:289)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your `org-info.js` file does not seem to match where the file actually is.

You have the file at: http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/js/org-info.js

But your example page is expecting it to be at: http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/docs/js/org-info.js

If you move the `js` folder to the `docs` folder, or change

```
#+INFOJS_OPT: path:js/org-info.js
```

to

```
 #+INFOJS_OPT: path:/js/org-info.js
```

it should work.

Comment: Thanks! though when I add the forward slash, I see no change in behavior (the hyperlinked files have been updated). Normally, whenever "path" does not point to the actual `org-info.js` file (e.g. I add an arbitrary typo), the .html file just looks empty, so perhaps `path:js/org-info.js` and `path:/js/org-info.js` are actually both pointing to the correct path.

Comment: Oh, hmm, how about if you try  `#+INFOJS_OPT: path:/~ksb/js/org-info.js`?

Comment: When I do that, I get the same behavior as any incorrect path to `org-info.js` (e.g. the same result as `#+INFOJS_OPT: path:/js/ooo-oooo.js`). The page is basically blank ([html](http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/docs/minimal_org.html),[org](http://web.stanford.edu/~ksb/docs/minimal.org)).

Comment: Hmm, it looks as if it's finding the file now, but it's resulting in a JavaScript error. `TypeError: k.T is undefined`.  Not sure what that problem would be!  I might have a try at recreating it later on.

Comment: I see now from inspecting the webpage. The error I see in "console" is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined` - I'm a bit clueless about javascript but this brings me much closer to a solution, thanks!

Comment: any update on this issue. Is org-info.js in a working state? I am seeing a crash in org-info.js as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode')`. The stack trace is ```at Object.initFromTOC (org-info.js:719:37)
    at Object.init (org-info.js:509:15)
    at OrgHtmlManagerLoadCheck (org-info.js:2120:20)
    at <anonymous>:1:1```

Answer (score 1):

There is a related discussion over at the org-mode mailing list:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-11/msg00702.html

In brief, this is probably a bug in org-mode, and a workaround is possible by putting `#+TITLE: some_title` at the top of your org file.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Org mode would export HTML with `<details>` and `<summary>` tags.  That would result in the functionality you want without the need for JavaScript.

```
<details>
<summary>Heading</summary>
The visibility of this text will be toggled when you click on "Heading"
</details>
```

Because Org mode does not export HTML code this way, you need to add some simple JavaScript to the page:

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").forEach(function(heading) {
  heading.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling
    content.style.display = content.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
  })
})
```